# Force user to crop/upload an image to a certain size? Preferably using filepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, filepicker.io

I have users uploading images using filepicker, but I want them to have to upload an image of a certain size (and crop if the image is too big). I could cut it myself, but then it won't look good. Ideally, the user would crop it themselves.

I've tried this page: https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file-ingestion/widgets/pick?v=v2 and I've tried various options but nothing seems to work quite well.

`data-fp-image-min` doesn't prevent users from uploading smaller images. `data-fp-crop-force` along with `data-fp-crop-max` and `data-fp-crop-min` doesn't do the trick either.

I'm open to using other image uploading libraries, but I like using filepicker. Seems like this is something other people would have run into.

I'm using rails btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file-ingestion/widgets/pick?v=v2):

> data-fp-image-min - Images smaller than the specified dimensions will be upscaled to the minimum size.

So it doesn't really prevent users from uploading smaller images.

data-fp-crop-max and data-fp-crop-min specifies the maximum and minimum dimensions of the crop area so it won't give you specific dimensions.

I would recommend you to:

1. Set data-fp-crop-ratio - Specify the crop area height to width ratio. User will be able to adjust the crop area for each photo with desired ratio.
2. Set data-fp-crop-force="true" - User could not skip cropping image.
3. Then resize image to specific height or width.

This will result, you will always get the image with the desired dimensions.

Example for 150 x 200 image output:
Html widget:

```
<input type="filepicker" 
 data-fp-crop-ratio="3/4" 
 data-fp-crop-force="true" 
 mimetype="image/*" 
 onchange="window.upload(event)"
 data-fp-apikey="APUGwDkkSvqNr9Y3KD4tAz" />
```

Javascript:

```
window.upload = function(event){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.fpfile));
    var listElem = document.createElement("li");
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    /*
        set w=150 (width) conversion option
        so all images would be 150x200
        and crop_first option to make sure the image is cropped 
        before any other conversion parameters are executed.
    */

    image.setAttribute('src', event.fpfile.url + '&w=150&crop_first=true');
    listElem.appendChild(image);
    document.getElementById('results').appendChild(listElem);
};
```

Here is working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/krystiangw/9o9ebddL/

Comment: I ended up figuring it out on my own, but I did the exact same thing. Thanks for the help, regardless! You deserve the accepted answer.